# How can I retrieve all my contacts from iCloud back up to my iPhone?

Tags: icloud, contacts, restore

How can I retrieve all my contacts from iCloud back up to my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

To recover data from an iCloud backup you need to restore the whole backup onto an iPhone. All data currently stored on the phone will be lost as part of the process.

As you are already using iCloud, you might also find your contacts by directly logging in on icloud.com with your Apple ID. This of course will only work if you've configured your phone to sync with iCloud.